# Changing how Antlr4 prints a tree

Tags: regex, parsing, intellij-idea, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 in IntelliJ to make a small compiler for arithmetic expressions.
I want to print the tree and use this code snippet to do so.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tree");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    TreeViewer viewr = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
    parser.getRuleNames()),tree);
    viewr.setScale(2);//scale a little
    panel.add(viewr);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

This makes a tree which looks like this, for the input `3*5\n`

[image]

Is there a way to adjust this so it reads from top to bottom

```
                    Statement

              Expression         /n
         INT      *     INT 
          3              5
```

instead?
My grammar is defined as:

```
grammar Expression;

statement:   expression ENDSTATEMENT           # printExpr
        |   ID '=' expression ENDSTATEMENT     # assign
        |   ENDSTATEMENT                       # blank
        ;

expression:   expression MULTDIV expression      # MulDiv
          |   expression ADDSUB expression       # AddSub
          |   INT                                # int
          |   FLOAT                              # float
          |   ID                                 # id
          |   '(' expression ')'                 # parens
          ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
MULTDIV : ('*' | '/');   //match multiply or divide
ADDSUB  : ('+' | '-');   //match add or subtract
FLOAT:  INT '.' INT;     //match a floating point number
ENDSTATEMENT:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WHITESPACE  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // ignore whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not without changing the source of the tree viewer yourself.